# Android Emulator on Ubuntu 20.04 keeps terminating even when Graphics chosen as Software. Segfault in QEMU

Tags: android, android-emulator, nvidia, ubuntu-20.04

I have been trying to get the Android Emulator working, but have not been able to get it working.

When I try to initiate the AVD (Emulator v32.1.4), I get a terminated error, and when I check the logs i get this

```
2023-08-10 16:47:50,538 [  20100]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 30 - Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
2023-08-10 16:47:50,539 [  20101]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 30 - Found systemPath /home/aubuntu/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis_playstore/x86/
2023-08-10 16:47:50,853 [  20415]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 30 - Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
2023-08-10 16:47:50,855 [  20417] SEVERE - Emulator: Pixel 7 Pro API 30 - Emulator terminated with exit code 139
```

From various forums I saw that turning gpu off atleast got the AVD started. So for that, I went to the Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -avd  -gpu software
to No avail

I also tried -gpu host

The machine is an ASUS ROG STRIX, dual booted, and i see the NVIDIA Corporation / NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 shown under Graphics (when i click on About)

I have checked the space, and there is more than 50GB space available

WHen I run dmesg, i see the a segfault error with qemu

```
[    9.855177] Started bpfilter
[    9.923145] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[   11.079720] audit: type=1326 audit(1691666131.236:99): auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 ses=4294967295 subj=snap.cups.cupsd pid=2817 comm="cupsd" exe="/snap/cups/980/sbin/cupsd" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=93 compat=0 ip=0x7fb8b7999c4b code=0x50000
[   59.990415] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4055.0008: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
[  150.744978] qemu-system-x86[14224]: segfault at 7fffa27e7ff8 ip 00007f5048690274 sp 00007fffa27e8000 error 6 in libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4[7f5048673000+46000]
[  150.744993] Code: 48 8b 45 e0 48 8b 7d e8 48 89 07 c6 45
```

Any pointers on how to proceed will be helpful

```
aubuntu@aubuntu-ROG-Strix-G512LI-G512LI:~$ nvidia-smi
Thu Aug 10 16:53:40 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.86.05              Driver Version: 535.86.05    CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti     Off | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   57C    P8               4W /  50W |    116MiB /  4096MiB |      4%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1788      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          113MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     24280      G   gnome-control-center                          1MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
aubuntu@aubuntu-ROG-Strix-G512LI-G512LI:~$ sudo lspci -v | grep -i vga
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: Second VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f95 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: VGA
```

aubuntu@aubuntu-ROG-Strix-G512LI-G512LI:~$ prime-select query
nvidia

I do not have a second monitor connected (read that this could lead to issues,so have that disconnected)

Uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio and SDK kits multiple times
I have secure boot disabled
Virtualisation is enabled in BIOS
I upgraded NVIDIA drivers to 535 (it was at 510 earlier)

PS: I do have an Android Studio Canary version installed earlier, which I can see i havent fully been able to get rid of. Hitting remove hasnt quite worked

```
aubuntu@aubuntu-ROG-Strix-G512LI-G512LI:~$ lscpu
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          16
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-15
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              8
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           165
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10870H CPU @ 2.20GHz
Stepping:                        2
CPU MHz:                         2200.000
CPU max MHz:                     5000.0000
CPU min MHz:                     800.0000
BogoMIPS:                        4399.99
Virtualization:                  VT-x
L1d cache:                       256 KiB
L1i cache:                       256 KiB
L2 cache:                        2 MiB
L3 cache:                        16 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-15
```

Things tried:

- Reboot
- Reinstall of Android studio and Android SDK kit
- Delete AVD and recreate with various memory configurations (higher
  and lower)
- Check for space issues
- Purge Nvidia drivers, and reinstalled the latest one 535
- Check if GPU is utilised (it is)
- Removed any secondary monitors
- Check is secure boot is
  disabled
- Checked several forums for a lead
  FURTHER EDIT

When I saw journalctl I see this error

```
ug 11 17:19:50  systemd-coredump[29883]: Process 29881 (qemu-system-x86) of user 1000 dumped core.

tack trace of thread 29881:
0  0x00007f398b945236 _ZN8tcmalloc10SLL_TryPopEPPvS1_ (/home/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal.so>
1  0x00007f398b94519f _ZN8tcmalloc11ThreadCache8FreeList6TryPopEPPv (/home/ashleyubuntu/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libtcmal>
2  0x00007f398b96041a tc_new (/home/ashleyubuntu/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4 + 0x3841a)
3  0x00007f398ad93b1a n/a (/home/ashleyubuntu/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libandroid-webrtc.so + 0x10d8b1a)
4  0x00007f398ad93b3a n/a (/home/ashleyubuntu/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libandroid-webrtc.so + 0x10d8b3a)
5  0x00007f398ad93b3a n/a (/home/ashleyubuntu/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libandroid-webrtc.so + 0x10d8b3a)
6  0x00007f398ad93b3a n/a (/home/ashleyubuntu/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libandroid-webrtc.so + 0x10d8b3a)
7  0x00007f398ad93b3a n/a (/home/ashleyubuntu/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libandroid-webrtc.so + 0x10d8b3a)
```

Comment: Downgrading Android Emulator to 31.3.14.0 got the emulator working for me. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive